# Java Threads Throw exception

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, arraylist, iterator

I try to do a supermarket checkout system using threads. Every client has an id and a waiting time. Add a client to the checkout with the smallest waiting time. A checkout waiting time is the sum of waiting times of the clients from that checkout. The waiting time is in seconds and at every second is decreasing. When a client waiting time is 0 i need to delete it from queue and here is the problem. It keeps throw an exception

```
public class Checkout extends Thread{


    public ArrayList<Client> clients = new ArrayList<Client>();
    public ArrayList<Client> deleted = new ArrayList<Client>();
    Iterator<Client> it = clients.iterator();
    int sum=0;
    View v;
    Shop m;

    public Checkout(String nume) {
        setName(nume);
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
                while(true)
                {
                    delete_client();
                    sleep(1000);                
                }
        }catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public synchronized void add_client(Client c) throws InterruptedException{
        clients.add(c);
        sum=sum+c.getWaintinTime();
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void delete_client()throws InterruptedException{
        while (clients.size()==0)
            wait();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Client c = it.next();
            if(c.getDecrement()==0)
            {
                v.display("\nTime: "+ m.curentTime +" Client "+Long.toString(c.getID()+1)+" leaved the checkout " + getName());
                deleted.add(c);
            }
            clients.removeAll(deleted);
        }
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized long waiting_time() throws InterruptedException{
        notifyAll();
        return sum;
    }

}

public class Shop extends Thread {

    private Checkout checkout[];
    private int nr_checkouts;
    static int id =0;
    private int nr_clients;
    public int waitingTime; // random from interval (wMin, wMax)
    public int wMax,wMin; //get them from TextFields
    View v;
    Random r = new Random();

    public Shop(View v, int wMin1, int wMax1, int nr_checkouts, Checkout checkout[], String name, int nr_clients) {
        setName(name);
        this.v=v;
        this.wMax=wMax1;
        this.wMin=wMin1;
        this.nr_checkouts = nr_checkouts;
        this.checkout= new Checkout[nr_checkouts];
        this.nr_clients = nr_clients;
        for(int i =0; i<nr_checkouts;i++) {
            this.checkout[i]=checkout[i];
        }
    }

    private int min_index() {
        int index = 0;
        try {
            long min = checkout[0].waiting_time();
            for(int i =1 ; i<nr_case;i++) {
                long lung = casa[i].waiting_time);
                if(lung<min) {
                    min = lung;
                    index = i;
                }
            }
        }catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return index;
    }

     public void run(){ 
             try{
                 int i=0;

                 while( i<nr_clients ){
                     i++;
                     waitingTime = r.nextInt((wMax-wMin)+1)+wMin;
                     Client c = new Client(waitingTime,id++);
                     int m = min_index(); 
                     currentTime++;
                     checkout[m].add_client( c ); //add it ad the checkout with minimum waiting time
                     v.display("\nTime "+ currentTime +" Client " +Long.toString( id )+" | with waiting time  " + waitingTime+" | came at checkout  "+ Integer.toString(m));
                     sleep( 1000 );
                 }
             }
             catch( InterruptedException e ){
                 System.out.println(e.toString());
             }
        }
    }
public class Client {

    private int waitingTime;
    private int id=0;

    public Client(int waitingTime,int id)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.waitingTime = waitingTime;
    }

    public int getDecrement() {
        return this.waitingTime--;
    }
```

I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "Checkout 1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
at thread.thread.Checkout.delete_client(Checkout.java:55)
at thread.thread.Checkout.run(Checkout.java:35)
```

Line 35: `delete_client();`
Line 55: `Client c = it.next();`

Comment: Either move `clients.removeAll(deleted);` out of the loop, or use [`Iterator.remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--)

Answer (score 2):

The **ConcurrentModificationException** is thrown when two threads want use the same resource at the same time.

You use the **synchronized** keyword and that is good, but the exception happens because you call *delete_client* inside the same class without another lock object. The [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) says:

> **First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave.** When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.

So, you can do the following:

```
private final Object countLock = new Object();
.
.
.
while(true)
{
   synchronized (countLock) {
       delete_client();
   }
   sleep(1000);                
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call modify methods such as `removeAll` when iterating a `List`, it will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

You can do it this way:

```
it = clients.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    Client c = it.next();
    if(c.getDecrement()==0)
    {
        v.display("\nTime: "+ m.curentTime +" Client "+Long.toString(c.getID()+1)+" leaved the checkout " + getName());
        deleted.add(c);
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: i modify and it's still the same.

Comment: @Siespi Try create the iterator before the while loop. See my updated answer.